# Google Sheets: Counting data from a moving range

Tags: google-sheets

So, I'm not amazing with Google Sheets, I'm ok but nothing crazy. I'm looking for a formula or method of counting data from the last 5 entries. These entries are added 3 times a week and the range would need to move automatically for this to function properly.

First off, is this actually possible?
Secondly, if it is, how would I go about counting 3 different criteria's from a moving range?

Here's a link to the example spreadsheet I created.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/192fZVzqq-ML3YplTSKUlVNuEMXCAfePE1IYzYPikukQ/

There are 5 "people" and 13 entries for each person which is either "Yes", "No", or "Ab". The actual entry itself is not important but I'd like to be able to count, say, the last 5 entries.

If anyone here knows how to do this, or if this is even possible, please help me.

Comment: Your intent in saying "the last 5 entries" is not immediately clear to me. Will you be adding ROWS to this data, or COLUMNS? If columns, you shouldn't have your formula results to the right of the data, since the data will continually expand to the right. Also, is the additional data going to be added manually or by form/script? If manually, there is a better way to set up your data. In addition, Col M and N have the same date. Is this an error? If not, are M and N a separate 2 entries of the last 5? A lot still needs clarification here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose **Insert > New sheet** and use this formula to get the last five columns:

`=transpose( query( transpose(Example!A1:ZZ), "where Col1 is not null order by Col1 desc limit 5", 1 ) )`

The five most recent dates will be shown in reverse order, latest date first.

Then use a regular `countif()` formula, like this:

`=countif($E3:3, A$2)`

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/192fZVzqq-ML3YplTSKUlVNuEMXCAfePE1IYzYPikukQ/edit#gid=1672341574).

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't even know that was a thing :D
This seems to work on the surface, I guess only time will tell if it works in practice.

Thanks!